Need help to use Safe-CLI to regain funds from a replayed Safe on Base
Managed to replay a safe wallet on Base with the same ETH address 0x88470174477D5fFa56758162781F96a85c62CDb8 originally created with a Ledger-Metamask.
Sadly the web UI no longer works:

So I proceeded to install Docker and run Safe-CLI:

I'm out of my depth at this point and need some handholding for exactly what commend lines to run in order to transfer the funds to a stable Base address.
Many thanks in advance.

You can look at this answer for detailed instructions on how to recover funds using the CLI.
Let me know if you encounter any problem! Thanks in advance 
Best, Louis

You said on the other thread that for Base change endpoint to
base-mainnet.infura.io/v3/
But I saw no Base option for my free account 1 API-KEY... Do I need to pay to get my Base API-Key? Thanks

You need to create an account on Infura for free, then you can use this key with all the network endpoints you want to interact with  Best, Louis
